# Adressess in dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Why don't all these addresses equal each other? &wsk[0][0] equals wsk[0] and it's logic, but wsk is different. Why? The name of array is also an address of array.

```
#include<iostream>

  using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int** wsk = new int* [2];
    wsk[0] = new int[2];
    cout << &wsk[0][0] << endl;
    cout << wsk[0] << endl;
    cout << wsk << endl;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *The name of array is also an address of array.* -- You don't have arrays in your code.  You have all pointers.  Also, how would you `delete` the memory you allocated?  Aha -- two different calls, right?  So it makes sense that the pointers are different, no?

Comment: The wsk[0] you allocated with different new than wsk. You used two different calls to new. So these are two different pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can literally change your code this way, so you will understand it better:

```
int main()
{
    int** wsk = new int* [2];
    int* wsk0 = new int[2], *wsk1 = new int[2];
    wsk[0] = wsk0;
    wsk[1] = wsk1;
```

You generate three different pointers. First one contains two pointers. All three pointers pointing to separated addresses.

The following constructions contains a single constant pointer, pointing to a contiguous memory location containing four elements, so in this case &msx will equal wsk and will will equal &wsk[0] and &wsk[0][0] as well:

```
int main()
{
    int wsk[2][2]; //in mmemory elements are located one by one
    cout << reinterpret_cast<long>( &wsk) << endl;
    cout << reinterpret_cast<long>( wsk) << endl;
    cout << reinterpret_cast<long>( &wsk[0]) << endl;
    cout << reinterpret_cast<long>( &wsk[0][0]) << endl;
```